# single key value update inside array object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have trying to update the single key value Array object
inside MongoDB collection. But It updates all the value with single key value.

Previous Json Data inside MongoDB

```
result: [
    {        
      "firstname": A,
      "lastname": B,
      "age": 5     
    }
]
  "_id" : "582187d461cc8230bf0aba03"
```

What I am doing I am updating single key value
I want to update only single key value
firstname : A to D and I need all remaining value must same(persist).
But got changed and only single key value pair updated.

```
 {
   result: [
   {        
     "first name": A 
   }
   ]
  "_id" : "582187d461cc8230bf0aba03"
  }
```

Both lastname and age are gone. I am using node js to update the collection.

using this script

```
  var query = {"_id" : "582187d461cc8230bf0aba03"};
  var arr = [];
   userObj = {
   firstname : B
  };
   arr.push(userObj);
  update = {
  result : arr
   };

  var = options = {new : true, upsert : true};

   user.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, result)   { 
   if(err);
    console.log(err); 
    res.send(result);
   }
```

There is any command so i can update only single key value and all value will persist in collection

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so by default when you do an update, it will replace document A with document B.

You want to use the [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to only update the specific fields instead of replacing your entire document.

So for instance if you have:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Smith",
  phone_number: "(123)456-7890"
}
```

and you do

```
db.user.update({_id: 123}, {first_name: "Bob"})
```

you will replace the whole document and get:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  first_name: "Bob"
}
```

but if you do:

```
db.user.update({ _id: 123 }, { $set: { first_name: "Bob" } })
```

you will get your expected result of:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  first_name: "Bob",
  last_name: "Smith",
  phone_number: "(123)456-7890"
}
```

In your case, you can try this:

```
var obj = {
  firstname: B
};

user.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$set: obj}, options, function(err, result)
```